# Bash: how to detect error in pipe

Tags: bash, shell

I have commands like this:

```
COMMAND1 &&
COMMAND2 | COMMAND3 | COMMAND4 &&
COMMAND5
```

I want to make sure all of the COMMAND 1-5 are successful.  Is there an easy way to achieve this?  By doing research, I found PIPESTATUS can be used, but yield to some very complicated commands like

```
COMMAND1 &&
COMMAND2 | COMMAND3 | COMMAND4 &&
($PST=("${PIPESTATUS[@]}") && (exit ${PST[0]}) && (exit ${PST[1]})) &&
COMMAND5
```

Is there a way to do it easily?

BTW: I used (exit n) to get a command that does nothing but exit with status n.  Is there a UNIX command that does this directly, like true and false?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `set -o pipefail`?

Comment: This exactly solves my problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `set -o pipefail`.  This ensures that the error code of the pipeline is the error code of the last process with an error.

Comment: Sadly, it's only available in *bash*, not sh :(

Comment: that's true, but the original question referred to bash.